# Store assumptions of timezone in django model?

Tags: mysql, django, timestamp, timezone, mariadb

I have a MariaDB table with UTC datetimes in it.  However, I cannot seem to get Django to use those without throwing a warning that I am feeding it naive datetimes when timezone support is active.  Is there some way I can specify in the model that it is UTC datetimes stored in the database?  I checked and it looks like MariaDB won't get a datetime column with timezone support (in a `2020-04-20 04:20:00-07:00` type of fashion) until the future.

I've heard that Postgres doesn't have this problem but I am in no mood to migrate the database yet again.  Code for the model is below—ideally, I'd convert into an aware datetime somewhere in the model rather than run the conversion every place the data is used.

```py
class NstRotationDate(models.Model):
    num = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    special_note = models.CharField(max_length=123, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Have you read the [timezone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/)? Where is the code that actually throws a warning?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and MariaDB do not recognize `-07:00` or `T` in either `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` literals.